# Calculating distance when velocity is given

Tags: integration

How to find the distance in $0 < t < 2$ when the velocity is given:

$$v(t) = \frac{t^3}{10} - \frac{t^2}{20} + 1$$

I have tried the following and got the answer as $2.267$

\begin{align*}
d = \int_{0}^{2}v(t)\mathrm{d}t & \Longleftrightarrow d = \int_{0}^{2} \left(\frac{t^{3}}{10} - \frac{t^{2}}{20}+1\right)\mathrm{d}t\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow d = \left(\frac{t^{4}}{40} - \frac{t^{3}}{60}+t\right)\Big|_{0}^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow d = 2.267 m
\end{align*}
Is this approach correct? Kindly help.

Comment: Without absolute value, it is correct.

Comment: What you mean by "Without absolute value"? could you please help eloborate

Comment: $d=\int_0^2v(t)dt$ not $ |v(t)|$.

Answer (score 3):

There is a distinction between the difference of the particle's position  between the instants $t_{2} > t_{1}$ and the distance traveled by the particle corresponding to the time interval $\Delta t = t_{2} -t_{1}$. The first is given by the integral of $v(t)$ and the second is given by the integral of $|v(t)|$. Depending in which case you are interested, you can calculate the corresponding integral in order to obtain the answer.